# Is polynomials of pair degree a vector space?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

How can we prove the above statement? additionnaly , if we take only polynomials with monomials of pair degree can we conclude the same, is it a subspace of $K_n[X]$?

Comment: Do you mean even degree?

Comment: Nope. It is not closed under addition: for example, consider $x^2$ and $-x^2+1$. Their sum has odd degree.

Comment: @Crostul No it doesn't, but you're not wrong about it not being closed under addition.

Comment: Yes I mean Even degree, can you shed light on the next question? thank you

Comment: Crostul meant $x^2$ and $-x^2+x$. If you take polynomials which are sums of monomials of even degree, I don't see why not. All axioms of a vector spaces seem to be verified.

Comment: Okay I got it, the intuition is not fundamental in these cases... We will always have to verify all the axioms of a vector space (but it seems a tedious task) so everytime it's the useful thing to do , right?

Comment: Verify the axioms is always the thing to do. It is not as tedious as you would think in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To complete Bernard's answer*

To prove it (if you don't know what $K_n[X^2]$ means, or are not supposed to), refer to the DEFINITION of a vector space : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition

You have some very easy stuff to prove, one point of the definition at a time. Any set and pair of operations (sum and scalar multiplication) verifying these is a vector space.

Rq : The complete notation for this vector space is $(K_n[X],+,.)$; a set alone is not a vector space

Comment: I am aware of it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The set of polynomials of even degree is not closed under addition, hence it's not a subspace. But the set of polynomials with only monomials of even degree is a subspace of $K[X]$ since it is $K[X^2]$.